# How do I differentiate between Revit Parameter storage types since Revit stores Booleans as integer(1,0)?

Tags: c#, revit-api

I was trying to call up a list of Parameters (from two different families) in order to reconcile slight Parameter naming differences, and wanted to figure out what type of variable it was.  I tried the code below:

```
switch (One_Param.StorageType)
{
    case StorageType.Double: { Double_Params.Add(One_Param); break; }
    case StorageType.Integer: { Integer_Params.Add(One_Param); break; }
    case StorageType.String: { String_Params.Add(One_Param); break; }
}
```

This did not give me what I needed, since Booleans are stored as integers as are line weights.

The correct code would be:

```
switch (Bogus_Param.Definition.ParameterType)
{
    case ParameterType.Length: { Correct_Param.Set(Bogus_Param.AsDouble()); break; }
    case ParameterType.Number: { Correct_Param.Set(Bogus_Param.AsDouble()); break; }
    case ParameterType.Integer: { Correct_Param.Set(Bogus_Param.AsInteger()); break; }
    case ParameterType.Text: { Correct_Param.Set(Bogus_Param.AsString()); break; }
    case ParameterType.YesNo: { Correct_Param.Set(Bogus_Param.AsInteger()); break; }
}
```

NOte that there are several other ParameterType available, including Volume.  This sort of structure allows access to the "actual" storage type, and as long as you provide a valid value inside the .Set, this works well.  So you still provide an integer to both the YesNo and Integer ParameterType.

Answer (score 2):

FYI (with indirect suggestion via Spiderinnet):  The method is to use parameter.Definition.ParameterType.ToString(), which will return "Length", "Text", "YesNo", "Volume", "Integer", etc....Since I am only seeking the "YesNo", it is easy to get Boolean parameters, but this can also be used to compare other values.  This method also (nicely) returns a string "Invalid" for some other parameter types (not null).

Comment: Note that even though I alone answered my legitimate question, my score for the question remains zero.  It is important to know that StorageType is not as valuable as ParameterType.  Doesn't that rate a couple points?  And I can only increase the score for my question by editing it to no longer be a question at all, but just an answer?  This scoring thing on this site is cryptic and capricious.

Comment: You can't answer your own question and expect to get points for it. That would lead to some ridiculous behavior.

Comment: The basic complaint is that I was down-rated for no particular reason (since it was a legitimate question), but I can't at least get back to "1" for finding an answer and providing it to other people who might not know that "StorageType" is less useful than "ParameterType"